# How to prevent default functionality of paste event in monaco editor

Tags: javascript, paste, monaco-editor

How can I prevent default functionality for paste event (when trigger from browser menu option Edit->Paste) for monaco editor?
I am handling paste event in the following way:

```
    editor.getContainerDomNode().addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

I also tried to handle the paste event on the `textarea` which is the source element in event propagation.

```
    let textarea = editor.getContainerDomNode().querySelectorAll("textarea.inputarea.monaco-mouse-cursor-text")[0];
    textarea.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

But here also seems like `preventDefault` is not working. It is pasting into editor whatever the text is copied.

Bascially I want to disable paste action when triggered from browser Edit menu. Need to know how this can be achieve in monaco-editor. Am I doing anything wrong here or it is a bug of monaco editor?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the way an event is handled by listeners, when they are set on different ancestor elements.
An event is generally treated on a target element, then it "bubbles" on its ancestors.
On your case, you are adding a listener on a parent element of the editor. Which means that your listener will be executed **after** any listener on the actual target (which is actually how monaco handles the paste event).
So you are trying to prevent an action that was already executed.

Luckily, there is a way to achieve what you want! It is called "capturing".
By specifying in the call to `addEventListener` that you want to capture the event **on its way down**. This can be done by adding a third argument `{capture: true}`, or simply `true`:

```js
editor.getDomNode().addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
}, true);
```

This should prevent the editor from actually executing the action.
See [Documentation on bubbling and capturing events](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).